# What is empty statement record in PostgreSQL log?

Tags: postgresql, logging, configuration, duration, statements

I changed PostgreSQL cluster configuration to log ALL statements and its duration, and it work correct, but periodically I see records like this:

```
2020-12-08 09:31:42.175 +05 [19041:app_name] LOG:  00000: duration: 0.046 ms
2020-12-08 09:31:42.175 +05 [19041:app_name] LOCATION:  exec_execute_message, postgres.c:2086
```

What could it be? log_line_prefix = '%m [%p:%a] '

Also, it's standby node and replicates primary.

Comment: What are your settings for `log_duration`, `log_statement` and `log_min_duration_messages`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `log_duration = on`, `log_statement = 'all'`, `log_min_messages = warning`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `log_min_duration_statement = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing output from `log_duration`. That just emits the duration without the statement and is somewhat useless.

Set `log_duration = off`, `log_statement = 'none'` and `log_min_duration_statement = 0`, and you will get all statements logged along with their duration, which is usually the most useful setting.